# How to use AWS account_id variable in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want access to my AWS Account ID in terraform. I am able to get at it with `aws_caller_identity` per [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity). How do I then use the variable I created? In the below case I am trying to use it in an S3 bucket name:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
output "account_id" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-${account_id}"
}
```

Trying to use the `account_id` variable in this way gives me the error `A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.` I expect I'm not calling it correctly?

Comment: `"test-bucket-${account_id}"` should be `"test-bucket-${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"` - alternatively define a `locals` with that same value.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to not have to repeat `ata.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id` over and over. Know how to define locals assigned to the account_id?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you have a

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

then you need to define a `local` for that value:

```
locals {
    account_id = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}
```

and then use it like

```
output "account_id" {
  value = local.account_id
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-${local.account_id}"
}
```

Terraform resolves the `locals` based on their dependencies so you can create `locals` that depend on other `locals`, on `resources`, on `data` blocks, etc.

Comment: how to use this if you are using tfvars ?

Comment: @it_works_on_my_computer that is an entirely unrelated question / topic. tfvars are for statically hardcoding different variable values. This question is about dynamically determining the current account.

Answer (score 10):

Any time you create a datasource in terraform , it will export some attributes related to that datasource so that you can reference it somewhere else in your configuration and interpolate it with various ways.

In your case, you are already referencing the value of your account id in `output` block

So that same way, you can construct the string for the bucket name as follows.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
}
```

I would highly recommend you go through the terrraform syntax which can help you better understand the resource, datasource and expressions

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html

Comment: how to use this if you are using tfvars ?